# How do I do color space conversion with .NET?

Tags: colors, bitmap

It seems to me that the {System.Drawing.}Color struct is missing a .FromHSL method. Does one have to reinvent this wheel oneself or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is strangely missing from the FCL.

However, [someone else has already written it](http://splinter.com.au/blog/?p=29); you don't need to re-invent it yourself.